# Writing formula using Xlsxwriter in python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have this statement

```
worksheet.write_formula(j + 3, 5, f'=IF({xl_rowcol_to_cell(j + 3,4)}>=90,, " Exce")')
```

I want to write a formula in excel to compare the value of cell(j + 3, 5) if its value

- 90 write Excellent
- 80 write v. good
- 70 write good

i.e. examined cell value

Answer (score 0):

What you need are nested IFs, like:

```
worksheet.write_formula(j + 3, 5, f'=IF({xl_rowcol_to_cell(j + 3,4)}>=90;"Excellent";IF({xl_rowcol_to_cell(j + 3,4)}>=80;"Very Good";IF({xl_rowcol_to_cell(j + 3,4)}>=70;"Good";"")))')
```

Bear in mind that:

> XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead
> stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag
> in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be
> recalculated when the file is opened.

As per the documentation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html

Comment: Thank for your answer Iliya , and  what is the solution moving to another library ?

Comment: Hi, the result of the formula should calculate on opening the file with Excel. If you are not going to open the file with Excel, calculate the value with Python and store it using the optional value parameter. In the Formula Results section of the documentation is explained how to do this.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot to you , I have solved the issue>